# Isn’t ‘approximately’ an adverb?

Tags: adverbs

‘Approximately’ is an adverb and modifies a verb. Does that mean for example that ‘approximately five people’ refers to five people until there’s a verb included?

So my answer is: ‘approximately five people’ without a verb refers just to five people, and after a verb is included, for example ‘approximately five people have immunity against the virus’ it means ‘four to six people have immunity against the virus’?

++ Aren’t numerals determiners? Can adverb ‘approximately’ modify determiners?

Comment: Approximately, as an adverb, requires a verb. There is no meaning without a verb. So "approximately five people" as a response (say in dialogue) only makes sense if you assume a verb (approximately five people were present).

Comment: @FeliniusRex How would you explain "My car, approximately 20 feet long, does not fit into a standard parking space." It sure sounds as though "approximately" is modifying either "20 feet long" or just "20 feet", neither of which is a verb.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan My car (which IS) approximately 20 feet long...

Comment: _Approximately is an adverb and modifies a verb_. **Or other constructions**. It is simply not true that an  adverb requires a verb to modify.

Comment: @ColinFine Thank you. Just one more example: "Approximately 20 people participated in the riot." Surely no one would construe that as "People, who were approximately 20, participated in the riot."

Comment: Yes, it is an adverb serving semantically as a quantifier, and as such is a dependent of the determinative "five", which it combines with to form the determinative phrase "approximately five". The bracketing of the NP is: [approximately five] people]], which is functioning as predicative complement of "be".

Comment: It's very disappointing when some people obscure what is really simple by using terms not relevant to learners. I have to say that in my answer, I tried to give evidence for what I had to say: basically, this boils down to: adverb, adjective, noun. No one here is going to use correct CGEL terminology. Learners do not know it. And really do not need to know it to receive good answers.

Comment: Well, it's an adverb, but in a way that's approximately an adjective.

Comment: Adverbs hardly ever modify verbs. It's really very rare. On the other hand, they can modify *phrases* headed by almost any part of speech apart from nouns. The adverb "approximately" can modify numerals. It can't modify verbs. It's not your school teachers' fault that they taught you that adverbs can be defined as words that modify verbs. They were taught that too. It's never been true.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. If "approximately" can modify numerals (here a cardinal number), this is really very simple. As I have been saying all along. But for you, then, in:  The site was dated exactly. or:  The site was dated approximately, those adverbs don't modify those verbs?

Comment: @Lambie Those adverbs modify the verb *phrase* "[was [dated __ ]]", I believe. (Might be wrong.)

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Let's date this site exactly. We don't have much time. I know what you will say: It modifies "date this site" a *phrase*, whereas most of use would say it modifies how it will be dated: approximate dating and exact dating.

Comment: @Lambie Yes, how it "[will [be [dated __]]]". Notice that "approximate dating" and "exact dating" use adjectives to modify a deverbal noun, not a verb!

Comment: Personally, I would avoid saying, and above all, writing "approximately five people" it's such a small number easily verifiable. Using "approximately" **works better with fractions and larger numbers**, e.g. "Approximately 3 in 10 employees continue to  work from home" or  "Police estimates suggest **that approximately 30,000 protesters** marched to the European Parliament yesterday evening" If only four turned up nobody would use "approximately" there.

Comment: @Araucaria: About whether it can modify verbs... Let me know what you think of my answer. =)

Comment: *"the jug is approximately full"* is a pretty obvious counterexample that shows that *approximately* can modify adjectives(, numerals, etc.)

Comment: Approximately modifies "is" not the adjective or noun. Consider "We have approximately a half tank of gas.". Doesn't that say how you have a tank of gas?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> ‘Approximately’ is an adverb

Yes.

> and modifies a verb

Not necessarily. Adverbs can also modify adjectives, other adverbs, or in your case, numerals.

> ‘approximately five people’ without a verb refers just to five people

No, it still means something like 'four to six people'. If there is no doubt about the exact number, 'approximately' should be dropped.

You could arguably say it requires a verb because *every* [clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clause) requires a verb. But that is true for more word classes than adverbs ...

Comment: You're right about adverbs but I'm not convinced of your application in this example. When you say something *is* something ('is' is also a form of the verb *to be*) you are essentially saying they are the same thing. The mathematical equivalent would be saying '*equals*' - for example, "two plus two *is* four". Without the adverb in your example, you would be saying categorically that there *are* 5 people. Either that is true, or it isn't. So what is it really modifying?

Comment: It's still modifying 'five', and in the case of the OP the subject of the sentence, not the verb. "2 to the tenth power approximately equals a thousand" - then it modifies the verb (though I'd rather write "is approximately equal to").

Comment: @Glorfindel Normally doesn’t ‘approximately’ modify adjectives? Ex) He is approximately the size of mine.

Comment: @user284747 I see no adjective there? One could argue it modifies either 'is' or the entirety of 'the size of mine' (I'd be inclined to say the first, not sure what the grammar books say.)

Comment: The adverb "approximately" is semantically a quantifier, and as such is a dependent of the determinative "five", which it combines with to form the determinative phrase "approximately five". The bracketing of the NP is: [approximately five] people]], which is functioning as predicative complement of "be".

Comment: I have to disagree. Websters says that "The meaning of approximately is *in an approximate manner*". A number cannot act in any manner. It is really describing the manner in which you are making the statement.

Comment: @BillJ A quantifier helps to quantify something, so it must add detail. For example, "*nearly* 5" means slightly less than 5. "Approximately" does not help quantify it. It makes it more vague. Plus, you can use it with quantifiers - for example, you could ask "How **many** are there, approximately"?

Comment: @BillJ There may not be any "be" at all. "Approximately ten rabbits were seen eating the rows of lettuce in the garden".//also, there are approximate numbers **as opposed** to exact numbers.

Comment: Right, some quantifiers go before nouns and are therefore adjectives. Many people, some people, ten people.

Comment: @Astralbee Of course it's a quantifier in the OP's example "approximately five people"; what else could it be? It occurs with numerals where it's used to indicate approximation. Likewise, "nearly", "roughly", "almost" and the like.

Comment: @Astralbee I don't know what dictionary you're using, but it looks like you're taking one of several definitions and saying a usage is incorrect because it follows definition 2 instead of definition 1. Or maybe your dictionary is just poorly worded on this point. thefreedictionary.com defines "approximately" as "close to; around; roughly or in the region of". That definition is totally consistent with what Glorfindel says.

Comment: Adverbs less often modify words, they normally modify phrases. However, If one disregards interjections and takes the parts of speech to be: nouns, verbs, adjectives, adverbs, prepositions, determinatives, subordinators and coordinators, adverbs can modify every class of word  apart from subordinators (maybe) and co-ordinators (definitely). People used to think they couldn't modify nouns, but they can post-positively: *events recently ...*. Adverbs are not "words that modify verbs"!

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. She said briskly and brightly.

Comment: @Lambie Yes, and? (Sorry, accidentally deleted this before!).

Comment: It's not modifying "five," it's modifying "are."  Without it, the implied "are" is definite.  The adverb makes it indefinite or an approximation.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer In, for example, "There are approximately five people", the adverb "approximately" is modifying the determiner "five", which it combines with to form the determinative phrase "approximately five". The DP is functioning in (and is thus part of) the noun phrase "[approximately five] people]]", whose bracketing is as shown.

Comment: @jay Words can have many synonyms and definitions. But if you can't substitute one for the other, you've no argument. I can say "It is 5 miles, approximately" and "It is 5 miles, roughly speaking". I can't do that with "is close to" without completely rephrasing.

Comment: @BillJ your own sentence.  "are approximately".  Think of it this way; "two times three equals approximately seven."  Approximately has nothing to do with seven, which is a noun or a numeral.  Adverbs modify verbs, adjectives, other adverbs... Not nouns.  Approximately modifies the verb "equals" just as it modifies "are" in your sentence.

Comment: @Astralbee While Webster's dictionary does define **approximately** as "in an approximate manner", Webster's dictionary also defines **in an approximate manner** can be "used to indicate that a stated number, amount, or value is an approximation". See: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/approximately

Comment: @DavidHoelzer "Approximately" modifies "seven", which is a determinative, not a noun. "Equals" functions like "be", so the analysis is the same as "Two times three are approximately seven", where "approximately modifies the determiner "seven". Incidentally, adverbs freely modify noun phrases, and even occasionally nouns.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer  "Be" requires an AdjP or NP or certain kinds of PP as complement, but only a very limited range of adverbs, though the latter would be semantically inappropriate here. Note that "approximately" is a quantifier. In the DP "approximately seven", it is a sub-type of quantifier used to express approximation.

Comment: @slebetman "a *stated* number", yes. You are stating it in an approximate manner. Have you ever heard someone say "*approximate 5*"? Of course not. Yet you can say "negative 5".

Comment: @Astralbee I don't know what you are talking about but we are talking about the definition and usage of **"approximately"** and of course I and even you have heard people say "approximately 5". It's fairly common. Are you looking at a different question than this one?

Comment: @slebetman Do pay attention, Bond. I asked you about the validity of saying "approximate 5", **not** "approximately". I'm trying to express that this adverb cannot be acting on the number. My best example is if I answered "truthfully, 5" - that would not mean that the number itself is truthful, rather that the manner in which I answered is truthful. Sincerely yours (that means I'm sincere, not you), Astralbee.

Comment: @Astralbee "Sincerely yours" means that the designation "yours" is sincere. "Yours" is an adjective, as in, "This book is yours." "Sincerely" is an adverb modifying this adjective. Yes, it's not "you" that is sincere, but, grammatically, it's not "I" who is sincere either. The word "I" doesn't even appear, and even if you want to say that this is an elision for "I am sincerely yours", that is still a very different sentence from saying "I am sincere."

Comment: @Astralbee A dictionary definition is not necessarily a synonym that could be dropped into a sentence in place of the word being defined. For example, thefreedictionary.com defines "dog" as "Any of various carnivorous mammals of the family Canidae, such as the dingo." I could say, "Fred has a dog named Rover." No one would say "Fred has a any of various carnivorous mammals of the family Canidae, such as the dingo named Rover."

Answer (score 7):

> A number, a determiner, tells us how many items are in the set.  **In
> this sense, it is a modifier.**  When the number is two or above, the
> noun takes the plural form. [Note: modifiers can be nouns OR adjectives]
>
> The book has **two** hundred pages
>
> Bruce's workout lasted **five** minutes.

[grammar quizzes](https://www.grammar-quizzes.com/adj_numbermodifiers.html)

> Numbers: one, two, three Numbers such as one, five, eleven, two
> hundred are cardinal numbers. **We most commonly use cardinal numbers as
> determiners (before nouns)**. When we use them in this way, we can use
> other determiners such as articles (a/an, the) and possessives (my,
> your) in front of them. We can use cardinal numbers + of before
> determiners (one of my friends):
>
> She loves animals and has two dogs, three cats and one rabbit.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/number)

> **Some theories of grammar do not include determiners as a part of speech and consider "*two*" in this example [two hats] to be an adjective.**

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeral_(linguistics))

**Conclusion for purposes of learning English**:
So, that means that the word "**approximately" in "approximately five people"* (in sentences or as an answer in speech) can indeed be seen as **an adverb qualifying the modifier or adjective "five" (the cardinal number)**.

Reminder: Oxford Dictionaries via Google:

adverbs
a word or phrase that modifies or qualifies **an adjective, verb, or other adverb or a word group**, expressing a relation of place, time, circumstance, manner, cause, degree, etc. (e.g., gently, quite, then, there ).

For example:

- We drove approximately ten miles. [modifies the phrase "ten miles" or the number "ten"] This can be viewed two ways.  But it is still an adverb as per the definition.
- He only does the task approximately, not thoroughly. [modifies the verb do]

Answer; Yes, "approximately" is an adverb modifying the cardinal number used as an adjective.

Comment: Some of what you say is true but the logic is wrong and doesn't answer the question at all. Numbers *can* be an adjective, for example, "a ten-page book", but in your example of "this book has 200 pages", the number alone is neither a quality of the book *or* the pages. In the OP's example, '5' is not an adjective that describes the people, either.

Comment: @Astralbee Yes, the cardinal number 5 is a modifier before a noun **and** it is an adjective according to the Cambridge Dictionary. Adverbs can modify adjectives. Ergo, "approximately" the adverb modifies the cardinal number adjective "five". It answers the question completely, in fact.

Comment: five minutes, 200 pages and 5 people are all examples of cardinal numbers as modifiers i.e. adjectives modifying nouns. Thanks for downvoting me.

Comment: Well, I did give you an opportunity to improve the answer first! I only downvote if I think an answer is going to mislead, and for all the truthful quotations in this answer, I don't feel that it deals with the context of the OP's question.

Comment: @Astralbee Oh, you gave me the opportunity? There are approximate numbers and exact numbers. "Approximately five people" is really just: people = noun, five = adjective (cardinal number **as adjective**) and approximately an adverb. So simple!

Comment: @Astralbee Adjectives don't necessarily describe qualities of the thing that the noun refers to, they can modify the meaning in other ways. Virtual reality is not reality. A faulty proof is not a proof. An assistant chief is not a chief. An aspiring actor is not an actor.

Answer (score 7):

In English, an adverb can modify a verb or it can modify an adjective.

If you say, "Approximately five people are needed to do this job", "approximately" is modifying "five". "Five" is an adjective modify "people". "Approximately" is an adverb modifying "five". It is not exactly five, but approximately five.

Other examples of adverbs modifying adjectives:

"He is an extremely tall man." "Extremely" is an adverb modifying the adjective "tall".

"A darkly dressed man entered my office." "Darkly" is an adverb modifying "dressed". "Darkly" is not modifying the verb, "entered". He didn't enter darkly. He is dressed darkly.

Etc.

Frankly, I think "approximately" is rarely used to modify a verb. You could say, "He measured the fluid approximately", meaning the act of measuring was not exact but approximate. But that's fairly rare. Usually we use "approximately" to modify an adjective. Approximately some number, approximately a direction ("approximately due north"), etc.

Comment: Aren’t numerals determiners? Can adverbs modify determiners?

Comment: @user284747 In this case, yes. There are a lot of cases where that wouldn’t make sense, but if a coyote ate one of my three chickens, I might say, “The sadly two chickens left are eating like nothing happened.” That is, it’s sad that there are only two left. The chickens themselves are not sad. They’re oblivious.

Comment: And we could also say "it was very approximately twenty", where we now have an adverb "very" modifying the adverb "approximately". (Incidentally, "very approximately" strictly means it was very close to 20, but most people will read it as meaning not very close to 20).

Comment: @Davislor: That might be an idiosyncrasy of yours; I wouldn't understand "the sadly two chickens left" as meaning what you suggest. (Though for that matter, even "It's sadly impossible" seems wrong to me -- I'd have to write "It's, sadly, impossible" -- so this might have to do more with the use of "sadly" than with the fact that "two" is a numeral.)

Comment: @ruakh Okay, but you’d agree that “only two” is very common, right? So would you accept, “the sadly only two surviving chickens” as a better example?

Comment: @Davislor: "The only two" is fine, but "the sadly only two" doesn't parse for me. I just can't use "sadly" that way.

Comment: @ruakh Interesting! Where are you from, if you don’t mind saying?

Comment: @Davislor: I grew up in the Upper Midwestern U.S. (Michigan and then Ohio), but I've lived in the Pacific Northwest for the past several years. How about yourself?

Comment: @ruakh That’s even more interesting. Grew up all over the place, but mostly in Wisconsin, live in the PNW. And yet we use the word very differently. A quick Google search turns up thousands of examples (such as, “I shall certainly be reading the second of the sadly only two collections of his work.”).

Comment: @ruakh This usage was considered a gauche neologism a century ago, however. Etiquette books then told people to say, “It is to be hoped” instead of “hopefully,” “It is fortunate” instead of “fortunately,” and so on, unless the adverb modifies a verb.

Comment: @ruakh You seem to use “sadly” more conservatively than I do—am I correct that you would accept, “The sadly-singing swan,” as meaning that the swan sang sadly? Do you similarly reject, “I was able to catch the luckily also-delayed flight,” “The fortunately well-timed visit,” and so forth?

Comment: @Davislor: I'm certainly familiar with *sadly*, *fortunately*, *luckily*, *hopefully*, *happily*, etc., as sentence adverbs meaning roughly "It's [blah] that" or "I'm [blah] that"; it's just embedding them in the middle of a noun phrase, modifying part of that phrase, that doesn't seem to work for me. (But, yes, I would understand "the sadly-singing swan" to mean that the swan was singing sadly. Are you saying that *you wouldn't* understand it that way?)

Comment: @Davislor: The example you quote from a Google search sounds less bad to me, though, maybe because the "shall" signals that I'm going to have to make some allowances for grammar different from my own? :-P   I would phrase "the sadly only two collections" as "what are sadly the only two collections", optionally with commas around "sadly".

Comment: @ruakh We’d both understand “the sadly-singing swan” the same way. I was just checking. “I shall” was considered the proper conjugation in the nineteenth and early twentieth centuries, at the same time “the sadly only two” was more widely considered incorrect.

Comment: You have repeated my answer but provided no proof but I guess the OP is not interested in the proof.

Comment: @Lambie I’m interested in the proof.

Comment: @user284747 If that is so, I invite you to read my answer.

Comment: @MichaelKay - *Very approximately* is not used but we get your point.  No reason to mention it a third time.

Comment: @user284747 https://www.wordnik.com/words/adverb

Answer (score 5):

Simply put, "approximately" is an adverb that modifies the numeral determiner "five", resulting in "approximately five" behaving as a numeral adjective. This is in principle no different from how the adverb "very" modifies "big" in "very big mistake"; in general an adverb functions as a modifier that takes a phrase of some type and returns a phrase of the same type. Special cases have specific names; for example a lexical unit with the grammatical function (noun→noun) that also supports [degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_%28grammar%29) are called adjectives.

Note that "not" is also an adverb, and can modify noun phrases, verbs, adjectives and even other adverbs (e.g. "not a book", "did not go", "not good", "not very good"). Each adverb can modify only specific types.

Unfortunately, it seems that most lexicons do not clearly distinguish the different phrase types that "**approximately**" can modify:

1. **Numeral determiner**:   ~ five people;   ~ 30 boxes;   ~ 7 dollars.
2. **Noun phrase** (when meaning a quantity):   ~ a kilogram;   ~ twice as long;   ~ the size of a coin;   ~ the length of the street;   the number of people here today is ~ the same as yesterday.
3. **Verb** (when involving quantities):   ~ counting;   ~ computing;   measured it ~;   [~ speaking](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/business/1886516.stm).

In particular, it does not modify the noun phrase "five people" because that noun phrase is not a quantity, just like "very big mistake" cannot be parsed as "very { big mistake }". Neither can it modify the entire sentence "five people have immunity against the virus" or the verb "have" in that sentence.

Anyway, I want to emphasize that we cannot **prove** that "approximately" does **not** modify something. What matters is whether an explanation (e.g. the one I just gave) has greater explanatory power and predictive power than another one. Greater explanatory power means being able to account for all the usages with fewer rules. Greater predictive power means being able to generate never-before-seen example usages that native speakers would not only understand but also consider as normal.

Comment: I wouldn't go along with your comment "... resulting in "approximately five" behaving as a numeral adjective". It would better to say that it's a DP (determinative phrase) functioning as determiner in (and thus part of) the NP "[approximately five] people]]". The term adjective for such quantifiers was abandoned some years ago in favour of 'determiner'.

Comment: @BillJ: I understand that different people have different terminology and even different views regarding how to classify grammatical functions, so I don't have any objection should you have your own preferred system. Nevertheless, I think we surely agree that "approximately five" has the same grammatical function as "five" in that example. Correct? That's really the point I hope the asker gets; it is really just a matter of function. =)

Comment: It's a bit more than 'preferred' -- pretty much standard, I'd say. I agree that "approximately five" and "five" have the same function, in my terminology that of 'determiner'. Note that 'adjective' is a word category (part of speech) not a function.

Comment: @BillJ: I guess I'm outdated then, since "adjectival phrase" is a function type for me. =P

Answer (score -5):

The adverb 'approximately' is really describing the manner in which you are answering, not really the answer itself.

One synonym of 'approximately' is the phrase '*roughly speaking*', where the adverb 'roughly' is modifying the verb 'speaking'. You *could* say 'approximately speaking', but it isn't idiomatic to do so, and the word alone is really implying both.

Consider a similar example:

> -How many cookies did you take?
> -Truthfully, none.

The adverb 'truthfully' is not acting on the answer of "none" - a number cannot behave truthfully any more than it can behave approximately (and that's what 'approximately' means - *in an approximate manner*). 'Approximately' can only refer to *the manner* in which the answer is being given, and not the answer itself. You could also speak *generally*, *hypothetically*, and use these adverbs before you answer to show that is the manner in which the answer is being given.

You could also phrase your example as:

- Approximately, there are 5 people.
- There are, approximately, 5 people.

Sincerely yours (an adverb which means I'm being sincere, even though I'm not mentioned and there is no verb *to be*),
Astralbee

Comment: I wouldn't go along with what you say. The adverb "approximately" is semantically a quantifier, and as such is a dependent of the determinative "five", which it combines with to form the determinative phrase "approximately five". The bracketing of the NP is: [approximately five] people]], which is functioning as predicative complement of "be".

Comment: It isn't a quantifier. Consider this question - "How many are there, approximately?" It uses the adverb 'approximately' without a number. How? The word 'many' is an adjective AND a quantifier. It is asking you to answer *in an approximate manner*, and that is why would could answer "there are 5, approximately".

Comment: Approximately 100 persons survived the accident though many were taken to the hospital. [No "there are", no "be" verb and no question]. It seems to be that you are the one suffering from flawed logic as you make assumptions about the speaker and the speaker's speech.

Comment: @Lambie "survived" is the verb in your example. You've just scored a bit of an own goal.

Comment: Yes, I used another verb on purpose! First, to show that it's nothing to do with "There are" necessarily and, secondly, to show that approximately is not related to the verb survive in my example.

Comment: @Astralbee  I was of referring to your analysis of "There are approximately 5 people", as I showed in my comment. It's this use of "approximately" that the OP is asking about.

Comment: *I showed Bill approximately where the UFO landed.*  This is an adverb that modifies *showed*.   *I showed Bill approximately four UFOs.* This is an adjective modifying *four UFOs*.  Nothing was *shown approximately* here.  This raises a question with me as to whether *approximately four nouns* is a correct usage.

Comment: It is impossible for me to show someone *approximately four UFOs*.   In such a case *approximately* is an editorial comment provided by the speaker/writer and applying entirely to the number of UFOs.  In other words, the speaker does not know how many UFOs were present but they are making an estimate.  It has nothing to with the *showing*.

Comment: @EllieK The colocations are: approximate numbers and exact numbers. cardinal numbers. cardinal numbers are considered adjectives. Exactly 10 dollars, approximately 10 dollars.

Comment: Approximately means closely, not roughly. More approximate means more precise (but don't use the phrase, because half your readers don't know that.)

Comment: @lambie I completely agree that "an approximate number" is correct, where 'approximate' is an adjective describing 'number', a noun. It's the same structure as "a bad apple". But can you say "badly, an apple?" Of course not. A bad apple is not an apple that behaves badly. An approximate number is not a number that behaves approximately.

Comment: @Astralbee Now your logic is off because bad and badly are not approximate and approximately. You can do something badly and not be bad, right?

Comment: @Lambie That's exactly what I'm saying. I might answer approximately, but that doesn't make me approximate.